# Is there a difference between borrowing an argument as mutable and taking ownership of it and returning it?

Tags: rust

Consider:

```
fn main() {
    let mut words: Vec<String> = Vec::new();
    words.push(String::from("Example1"));
    do_something(&mut words);

    for word in words.iter() {
        println!("{}", word);
    }
}

fn do_something(words: &mut Vec<String>) {
    //modify vector, maybe push something:
    words.push(String::from("Example2"));
}
```

vs.

```
fn main() {
    let mut words: Vec<String> = Vec::new();
    words.push(String::from("Example1"));
    words = do_something(words);

    for word in words.iter() {
        println!("{}", word);
    }
}

fn do_something(mut words: Vec<String>) -> Vec<String> {
    //modify vector, maybe push something:
    words.push(String::from("Example2"));
    return words;
}
```

Both solutions will print:

```
Example1
Example2
```

Is there any difference? What should we use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there's really not much difference in the capability of code using one or the other.

Most of the benefits of one vs the other lie outside of pure capability:

Taking a reference is often more ergonomic to the users of your code: they don't have to continue to remember to assign the return value of each function call.

Taking a value vs. a reference is also often a better signal to your user about the intended usage of the code.

There's a hierarchy of what types are interoperable. If you have ownership of a value, you can call a function that takes ownership, a mutable reference, or an immutable reference. If you have a mutable reference, you can call a function that takes a mutable reference or an immutable reference. If you have an immutable reference, you can only call a function that takes an immutable reference. Thus it's common to accept the most permissive type you can.

Comment: Note: Unsized types are also notable for not being passable by value, which may limit one's options.

Comment: @MatthieuM. a good point! I assumed we were only taking into account places where both options were a viable possibility.

Comment: why ever write code that takes ownership instead of a mutable reference?

Comment: @minseong passing references requires that you deal with lifetimes, and a large number of people don't like doing that when not absolutely needed for performance.